# How can i get customer information in observer : Magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, adminhtml

Actually, I am trying to get customer data in observer and my event is

```
"adminhtml_customer_save_after"
```

I have made observer

Code:-

```
    <?php
/**
* Copyright � 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace Amitshree\Customer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


class Customersaveafter implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $_customerGroup;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
        $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    * @return void
    */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {

    echo "<pre>";
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    print_r($customer->getData());
    die('Observer Is called!');

    }
}
```

I want to get Customer infromation and i am trying to print customer in this file using

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $event->getCustomer();
print_r($customer->getData());
```

but don't get any result.

I have created events.xml in `etc/adminhtml/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="adminhtml_customer_save_after">
        <observer name="Amitshree_Customer_Customer_Save_After" instance="Amitshree\Customer\Observer\Customersaveafter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Comment: Please share your event file code

Comment: @SaurabhRanjan I have updated my answer

Comment: please try $customer->getId() id is getting or not?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya you are right i got id and email also.

Comment: @Jaimin You problem is solved. Great

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the id and email from observer as shown below,

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    $email = $customer->getEmail();
    $id = $customer->getId();
}
```

You can also get customer object with the below method,

```
print_r($customer->debug());
```

Comment: How I will get all the customer data or Params?

Answer (score 2):

If you need customers information you can do:

```
public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{

//echo "<pre>";
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $event->getCustomer();
print_r($customer->getEmail());
var_dump( $customer->getId());
var_dump( $customer->getName());
var_dump( $customer->getGroupId());
die('Observer Is called!');

}
```